# How to pass item data to click event with angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I would like to parse data from my item into the (click)-Event, but I think it is causing errors instead (application is suddenly blank).

How can I get item.HostName as a parameter into my click-event?

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of data" (click)="gotoEvent('{{item.HostName}}')">
  <p>{{item.UserName}}</p>
</ion-card>
```

thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove the **enclosing paranthesis** `'{{}}'`, pass it as a plain variable

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of data" (click)="gotoEvent(item.HostName)">
  <p>{{item.UserName}}</p>
</ion-card>
```